# Why is $Fg > n$ if you experience centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force

I have trouble believing two things at the same time. When an object is stationary on Earth, its free body diagram shows the object (for reference, let the object be presented in front of us like a portrait, with +ve $x$ and -ve $x$ to the left and right and up and down +ve $y$ and -ve $y$  respectively, as is natural) with its $x$ forces and $y$ forces balanced, hence it being stationary from an inertial observer, say, nearby. The $y$ forces are non-zero, but must resolve to $0$, as the person is stationary, namely $F_g$ and normal force $n$ anti-parallel to eachother. However, this makes the following argument hard to understand.

From a person outside Earth, they would conclude the inertial observer has a centripetal force as its net force, which could only be resolved by $$m\frac{v^2}{r} = F_g - n$$

However, this would seem to imply that $F_g > n$, otherwise $m\frac{v^2}{r} = 0$. However, if $F_g > n$ that seems to mean to me that, with that logic, I should be seeking into the floor. How can I accept both of these at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You are sinking towards the floor in a sense. You are accelerating towards the axis of rotation of the earth. You need to accelerate in this direction to move in a circle.

Comment: But how are we sinking towards the floor if our forces are balanced from our perspective?

Comment: By 'our perspective' I think you mean a rotating frame of reference. In a rotating frame of reference the sum of gravity and the centrifugal force is exactly balanced by the normal force so we don't fall through the floor. We usually don't bother thinking about the centrifugal force and just say 'effective gravity' is slightly weaker. But in a frame of reference where the earth is rotating, we are moving in a curved path and gravity needs to be stronger than the normal force to curve us like that.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the gravitational force is used to keep the object moving in a circle around the earth’s axis.  Otherwise, the object would move off on a tangent.  The remainder of the gravitational force is matched by the normal force.

Comment: Really? So $F_g = \frac{GmM}{r^2}$ is not the full magnitude of the force due to gravity then? Because that's the magnitude used for $F_g$ in our free body diagrams.

Comment: Do you really think that's what I said?  I said that part of  the gravitational force (i.e., part of $F_g=\frac{GmM}{r^2}$) is used to keep the object moving in a circle around the earth's axis (i.e., to provide the centripetal acceleration).  The remainder of the gravitational force is balanced by the normal force n.

Comment: Yes, but what my question is trying to get at is, when we say $F_g - n = 0$, is that not insinuating $\frac{GmM}{r^2} - n = 0$? Because, if this is true, there is no part of the gravitational force to supply this centripetal acceleration. If not, would $F_g$ in the case I described with $F_g - n = 0$, then must imply, with your logic, that $F_g = k \frac{GmM}{r^2}$ where $k$ is some constant, representing part of the total gravitational force while the centripetal force is the rest?

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly interpret what I said as implying that $F_g=k\frac{GmM}{r^2}$, with k being anything other than 1.0.  So, now its time to check your understanding.  True or false:  the normal force n is **ALWAYS** equal to $F_g=\frac{GmM}{r^2}$.  From your free body diagram for the case of the rotating earth, the number of forces acting on the object is (a) 0 (b) 1 (c) 2 (d) 3

Comment: No, the normal force is not always equal to $F_g$. In the case of, say, a rollercoaster going through a loop at the very bottom, the normal force is found from considering (in the $y$ direction only) $F_{y} = n - mg = m\frac{v^2}{r}$ so $n = m(g + \frac{v^2}{r})$. From the free body diagram for the case of the rotating earth, from the reference frame of someone outside Earth, .... I'm getting the feeling the exact same forces are occurring in this scenario as the one I just described? So (d)?

Comment: Answer (d) is incorrect (it should be only 2 forces).  But, I think you finally have the right idea.  In the case of a car or a roller coaster going over the top of a hill, the situation is very much the same as the scenario you described.  There are only two forces acting on your object:  gravity and the normal force.  The **net** of these two real forces is what we call the "centripetal force," and is equal to the mass times the centripetal acceleration $mv^2/2$.  But, the "centripetal force" is not a real force.  It is the difference between two real forces.